# post resource with associated file resource in a REST API

Tags: rest, file-upload, associations, api-platform.com

I have two entities, `MediaObject` and `Book`. `MediaObject` is a generic entity for managing files and includes fields like `size`, `mimeType`, and `filePath`. `Book` has fields like `title`, `author`, and also includes a link to an associated `MediaObject` for its `cover` image file.

How can I `POST` a `Book` entity with its associated `MediaObject` `cover` image with API-Platform? I'd like to do this as one atomic operation. I don't want books saved without a cover image and I don't want orphan cover images. So I don't want to `POST` a `MediaObject` cover image and then use the ID I get back when `POST`ing a new `Book`. (or vice-versa)

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/

```php
class MediaObject
{
    ...
    public $filePath;
    ...
}
```

```php
class Book
{
    ...
    public $coverImage; // i.e. mediaObjectId; associated MediaObject to an image file
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has the option `"deserialize"= false`. This means that deserialization will not occur for this operation. Therefore, you must write the entire deserialization process yourself to the handler controller. You must also write fields for the swagger documentation.

For example:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

// more use...

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     iri="http://schema.org/MediaObject",
 *     normalizationContext={
 *         "groups" = {"media:read"}
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "post" = {
 *             "controller" = MediaHandler::class,
 *             "deserialize" = false,
 *             "access_control" = "is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
 *             "validation_groups" = {"Default", "media:collection:post"},
 *             "openapi_context" = {
 *                 "requestBody" = {
 *                     "content" = {
 *                         "multipart/form-data" = {
 *                             "schema" = {
 *                                 "type" = "object",
 *                                 "properties" = {
 *                                     "file" = {
 *                                         "type" = "string",
 *                                         "format" = "binary"
 *                                     },
 *                                     "name" = {
 *                                         "type" = "string"
 *                                     }
 *                                 }
 *                             }
 *                         }
 *                     }
 *                 }
 *             }
 *         },
 *         "get"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"
 *     }
 * )
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MediaRepository")
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(iri="http://schema.org/contentUrl")
     * @Groups({"media:read"})
     */
    public $contentUrl;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"media:collection:post"})
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="media", fileNameProperty="filePath")
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="2M",
     *     mimeTypes={
     *         "application/pdf",
     *         "application/x-pdf",
     *         "image/jpeg",
     *         "image/jpg",
     *         "image/png"
     *     },
     *     groups={"media:collection:post"}
     * )
     */
    public $file;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512)
     */
    private $filePath;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    //...
}
```

Controller handler example:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Api;

// use ...

class MediaHandler extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request): Media
    {
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
        if (!$uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required');
        }

        $mediaObject       = new Media();
        $mediaObject->file = $uploadedFile;
        $mediaObject->setName($request->request->get('name'));

        return $mediaObject;
    }
}
```

If the "Book" exists. And you want to add `Book` to`MediaObject`, you can set the iri string and parse it in the controller-handler:

```
//...
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, IriConverterInterface $iriConverter)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->iriConverter  = $iriConverter;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request): Media
    {
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('file');
        if (!$uploadedFile) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('"file" is required');
        }

        $iriBook = $request->request->get('book');
        $book    = null;
        if ($iriBook) {
            /**
             * @var Book $book
             */
            $book = $this->iriConverter->getItemFromIri($iriBook);
        }

        $mediaObject       = new Media();
        $mediaObject->file = $uploadedFile;
        $mediaObject->setBook($book);

        return $mediaObject;
    }
//..
```

### If this is your case, then no further action (`DataPersist`) is required.

Next your need to go https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-persisters/ and make `DataPesist` handler

Example:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DataPersister;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface;
use App\Entity\Media;
use App\ExtendTrait\ContextAwareDataTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class MediaObjectDataPersister implements ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface
{
    use ContextAwareDataTrait;

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supports($data, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $this->isCollection('post', $context) && $data instanceof Media;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @param $data Media
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function persist($data, array $context = []): void
    {
        $book = new Book();
        $book->setName($data->getName());

        // begin transaction and persist and flush $book and $data
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function remove($data, array $context = []): void
    {
        // todo remove book
    }
}
```

P.S. I don't test this code. I writing idea ;)
P.S.S. `$this->isCollection()` it function from my trait, may be need you it:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\ExtendTrait;

/**
 * Trait ContextAwareDataTrait.
 *
 * Helps confirm the operation name
 */
trait ContextAwareDataTrait
{
    public function isItem(string $operationName, array $context, string $resourceClass = null): bool
    {
        if ($resourceClass && ($context['resource_class'] ?? false) !== $resourceClass) {
            return false;
        }

        return ($context['item_operation_name'] ?? null) === $operationName;
    }

    public function isCollection(string $operationName, array $context, string $resourceClass = null): bool
    {
        if ($resourceClass && ($context['resource_class'] ?? false) !== $resourceClass) {
            return false;
        }

        return ($context['collection_operation_name'] ?? null) === $operationName;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to address how you would include a MediaObject file upload with an associated resource, like a Book during a Book POST request

Comment: If the "Book" exists. And you want to add `Book` to `MediaObject`, you can set the iri string and parse it in the controller-handler

Comment: I edited the answer for a better understanding. I don’t know another way to reach your goal.